# How to connect kivy app to Android's installed app

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language, pyjnius, kivymd

I have created a basic kivy app which provides certain links. Assume I have created a button. And now, when I press the button , it should show me my device's installed apps like WhatsApp,Facebook, Instagram and  other apps to share this link.

Is this possible to do in kivy?if yes, then please do help me.

Comment: The two key steps are probably 1) find out how to get that information in java, and 2) do the same thing calling the java api with pyjnius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Native method for Android.
def share(title, text):
    from kivy import platform

    if platform == 'android':
        from jnius import autoclass

        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
        String = autoclass('java.lang.String')
        intent = Intent()
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String('{}'.format(text)))
        intent.setType('text/plain')
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, String(title))
        PythonActivity.mActivity.startActivity(chooser)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked successfully. Thanks for helping me out.